# visual studio namespace in code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

From some time whenever i download the webpages example from the Internet.In code behind file of `.aspx` page there is namespace mention before `public partial class` in some example.But it never worked for me. I'm using the vs2010 is this format used in previous version of Visual site and why vs2010 not support them.

Like in code behind file

```
namespace AutoCompleteTextBox
{
     public partial class AutoCompleteDemp : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: Please add a sample of what you think should work.

Comment: in .cs file namespace AutoCompleteTextBox
{
    public partial class AutoCompleteDemp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

Comment: but it not access the control of .aspx page. Untill i remove the namespace from the cs file

Comment: Update your question with the details, don't use the comments for things like that.

Comment: You may be seeing some examples using a web site "project" (File->New Web Site), and others using a web application project (File->New Project). Forget about web site "projects". They are very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `.aspx`'s `<@page>` directive has a matching Namespace:

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeBehind="AutoCompleteDemp.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoCompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteDemp " %>
```

Comment: Inherits is AutoCompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteDemp.but it still not work

Comment: Please share both your ASPxs @Page directive and the code behind. What is the exact error you're seeing?